# prevent css/jquery popups from allowing links underneath to be clicked (mobile only)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, mobile

so i have created !a simple popup using css and jquery.  the problem is, when the popup is activated, links underneath the popup can still be clicked.  is there any way to prevent this from happening.  the click box for some of the links in the popup are small and one can easily click next to it which means the link underneath the popup is clicked.

the site i am working on: taxslayerplayer.com, look at it on an android and you will see what i mean. also, i have experienced this problem on many other websites while browsing on my phone.

any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about a strictly-mobile solution, but you could check for the pop-up being visible and, if it's visible, simply `return false` in the click-handler for links:

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        return !$(this).closest(popupSelector).length;
}).on('click', function(e){
    if ($(popupSelector).is(':visible')) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // do whatever you'd normally do with the links
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could instead use a variable, for example `popupIsShown`, set it to `false` initially (on DOMReady), and then set it to `true` when the popup is shown, and reset to `false` when it's re-hidden, making the `if` check a little less expensive:

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        return !$(this).closest(popupSelector).length;
}).on('click', function(e){
    if (popupIsShown) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // do whatever you'd normally do with the links
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes; as currently written. I was going to suggest an alternative syntax for the selector in that children of the popup box wouldn't be affected, but, um...I got distracted. I'll add that in just a moment. *blush*

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have helped! ...and, obviously, the rep-reward is a nice bonus too! =)

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean value and set it to false in case of pop-ups. It works!

PS : Just checked.. David has already answered it.